# B is a subset of A. Both sets are closed. No point on the boundary of B is in the interior of A. Understanding conditions under which A= B.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $A$ is a  closed, bounded and connected subset of $R^d$. Suppose $B\subseteq A$, where $B$ is also closed, bounded and connected. Also, suppose that $A$ and $B$ have a non-empty interior in $R^d$. If no point on the boundary of $B$ is in the interior of $A$, then is $A=B$?

I was trying to prove this by contradiction. Suppose $B$ was a proper subset of $A$. I wanted to show that under the conditions of the above problem $A$ would be written as a union of two disjoint sets that would violate connectedness. However, I am unable to show this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $B$ could be a disc $\{z\in\mathbb C: |z|\le 1\}$ and $A=B\cup \{z\in\mathbb C: |z-2|\le 1\}$.

Comment: Thanks! that was very helpful.